# Understanding a step in the proof for $\pi(x) \le 6\log2\frac{x}{\log x}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I am reading through the following [paper](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/nt/cheb.pdf).

I am clear on this step:

$$\pi(2n) - \pi(n) \le 2\log2\frac{n}{\log n}$$

I am clear that if $4\le2^k<x<2^{k+1}$, then:

$$\pi(x) \le \pi(2^{k+1})\le 6\frac{2^k}{k+1}$$

The step that is unclear to me is the following:

$$6\frac{2^k}{k+1} \le 6\log2 \frac{2^k}{\log2^k}$$

Based on its form, it must somehow be related to $n=2^k$:

$$\pi(2n) - \pi(n) \le 2\log 2 \frac{2^k}{\log2^k}$$

But I can't see how.

---

Edit:  Donald Splutterwit provided the answer.

$$6\frac{2^k}{k+1} \le 6 \frac{1}{k}\frac{\log 2^k}{\log 2^k}(2^k) \le 6\log 2\frac{2^k}{\log 2^k}$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{k+1} \leq \frac{1}{k}$ ... $ \log 2^k =k \log 2$ & cancel $\log 2$ ?

Comment: Got it!  Thanks very much!  I'll update my question with your comment.